# Winedt environment indentation

Tags: editors, winedt

When I use the automatic environment in Winedt, it automatically creates a "2 space" indentation, as it follows

[image]

I'd like to know if there someway to change this space, I mean, I'd like to start typing "below" the "i" letter from "begin".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Answer rewritten after OP's comment</sup>

If you are inserting your `enumerate` through the `\begin{?}}` "active string", do the following

1. Open the file `CompleteEnv.edt` located in `C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\Macros\Active Strings` folder (or something like that).
2. Locate the line

   ```
      LetReg(7,'  ');");
   ```
3. Just after `LetReg(7,'` add two spaces (or how many you want).
4. At this point save the modified file in the folder `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\Macros\Active Strings` (create the path if it doesn't exist).

That's all.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using the menu "Insert". It's like: I write
`\begin{enumerate}}` and, when I add the 2nd `}` the editor create automatically the `\end{enumerate}`

Comment: @mvfs314 Ahhh, OK. Answer rewritten accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have the latest version.

In the `WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\Menus\Insert\` directory, open the `List.edt` macro file, and modify line 32:

```
Repeat(%!1,!'GotoCol(%!0+2);Ins("%!7");NewLine;');
```

to

```
Repeat(%!1,!'GotoCol(%!0+7);Ins("%!7");NewLine;');
```

Then save this version of List.edt to your personal WinEdt directory, more precisely in

```
C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\Menus\Insert\
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got a error message saying I can't save.

Comment: You perhaps don't have  admin rights. Anyway, it's better to save the modified List.edt in your *personal*  WinEdt directory. Please see my updated answer for details.

Comment: Well, I could save here (the main file), but it didn't change my request.

Comment: @mvfs314: Do you mean the last way I suggest (in your personal WinEdt directory) doesn't work for you?

Comment: No, the first way. I got the admin rights and I could change the line 32 and saved the file, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Anyway, it's better to put it in your personal WinEdt directory (in case of an update, it won't be overwritten). Do you have the latest version? Also, it changes the macro used  in the menu `Insert -> List -> Enumerate` (or itemize as well…). Is it the way you insert your enumerate environment?

Comment: Actually, I'm not using the menu "Insert". It's like: I write
`\begin{enumerate}}` and, when I add the 2nd `}` the editor create automatically the `\end{enumerate}`